# Clearing app data and changing orientation in @Before

Tags: java, android, junit4, ui-automation, android-espresso

In my espresso test I want to clear **app data** before each test run and also want to **change orientation** .

I am automating the onboarding process and the test cases are like-

1.LoginSuccessLandscape

2.LoginSuccessPortrait

3.InvalidMobile;etc

but after LoginSucessLandscape the app remains in the logged in stated so all my tests after that fails.

I want to clear app data after each test so that app remains on the onboarding page after each test run.

How should I implement this?